# python beautifulsoup4 find href link from the find_all result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've spend few days to make some program to crawl an website.

```
coin_link = requests.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin')
soup2 = bs(coin_link.text, "html.parser")

to_find_github_link = soup2.find_all('div',{'class':'tw-flex flex-wrap tw-font-normal'})
    
for x in to_find_github_link:
    time.sleep(1)
    Newx = x.text
    Newx = Newx.split()
```

When I print the result of x, one of the result contains what I looking for.

```
<a class="tw-px-2.5 tw-py-1 tw-my-0.5 tw-mr-1 tw-rounded-md tw-text-sm tw-font-medium tw-bg-gray-100 tw-text-gray-80
0 hover:tw-bg-gray-200 dark:tw-text-white dark:tw-bg-white dark:tw-bg-opacity-10 dark:hover:tw-bg-opacity-20 dark:focus:tw-bg-opacity-20"
href="https://github.com/bitcoin" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"><i class="fab mr-1 fa-github"></i>Github</a>
```

I wanna get the [href="https://github.com/bitcoin"] link out of the result.
I've tried to use the

```
x['href']
x.select['href']
```

such things but didn't work. I'm new to bs..
could I get some help?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

`['href']` is the right way, but the loop is a bit to much and you are not checking the contents or try to find the `<a>` that is holding the information you searching for.

#### How to fix and get the `href`

One way could be to select the `<i>` with class `fa-github` cause its parent is the `<a>` your are looking for:

```
soup2.select_one('i.fa-github').parent['href']
```

Alternativ with your loop:

```
to_find_github_link = soup2.find_all('div',{'class':'tw-flex flex-wrap tw-font-normal'})
    
for x in to_find_github_link:
    if 'Github' in x.text:
        print(x.a['href'])
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

coin_link = requests.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin')
soup2 = bs(coin_link.text, "html.parser")

soup2.select_one('i.fa-github').parent['href']
```

#### Output

```
'https://github.com/bitcoin'
```

Comment: Thanks :_ it works~!!! the first one. and also will try to learn about the parent option handling :)